# Rest Template issue with GET method while replacing ampersand

Tags: rest, get, resttemplate

I am hitting the below URL in postman -

`http://eghost.com?filter=SupplierCode='S&A'` - works fine with results

Hitting the same URL using Rest Template - Error

So I had to modify it like this - `http://eghost.com?filter=SupplierCode='S%26A'`

This works fine in Postman & Rest template as well without any error but getting no data as Rest Template is converting URL to this while hitting -

`http://eghost.com?filter=SupplierCode='S%2526A'`

I tried URLencoder which was of no help as it converts required characters to ASCII.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Ended up encoding my URL manually. Replaced space with %20 and ampersand with %26.

`URI uri = URI.create(ebxURL.replace(" ", "%20").replace("&", "%26"));
response = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);`